# Docusign powerform : number field is populating but validation error when autopopulated through query param

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk, powerform

I've a powerform generated from a template with lot of fields including number fields, date fields and text fields. I was able to successfully populate all the fields through the query parameter.
I've noticed one thing that the number field validation is failing in docusign. I've to edit the number again ( like clicking deleting and re-entering one number) to make the field valid and then only the submit button is enabling since this number field is a required field. I tried passing the number in formatted and non-formatted ways but no luck. Here are  few sample URLs to power form which I tried and attaching screenshot of one number field

```
https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId={id}&env=demo&acct={acct}&v=2&Client_UserName=Manu%20m&Client_Email=myemail.com&InitialDeposit=120000

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId={id}&env=demo&acct={acct}&v=2&Client_UserName=Manu%20m&Client_Email=myemail.com&InitialDeposit=120,000.00

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId={id}&env=demo&acct={acct}&v=2&Client_UserName=Manu%20m&Client_Email=myemail.com&InitialDeposit=120%2C000.00

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId={id}&env=demo&acct={acct}&v=2&Client_UserName=Manu%20m&Client_Email=myemail.com&InitialDeposit=120000.00
```

[image: Screengrab from docusign]

Answer (score 0):

Please open a Support Case (https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US) as we need more detailed information such as a request log.